# Error "ValueError: Please provide code or authorization_response parameters." for a Python app with the LinkedIn API deployed on Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, dockerfile, linkedin-api, google-cloud-run

I want to create a Python program, which will be deployed in a Docker container via a Google Cloud Run service, just allowing me to communicate with the LinkedIn API, and then go further into what the API offers.

after having performed the `gcloud run deploy` command which allows me to deploy the image in the container of my Google Cloud Run service, I have this error:

> ValueError: Please provide code or authorization_response parameters.

here is my directory tree containing all the files sent in the Docker container image:

- .dockerignore
- config (file with Client ID and Client Secret)
- Dockerfile
- main.py
- requirements.txt

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# imports
from flask import Flask, redirect, request
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from requests_oauthlib.compliance_fixes import linkedin_compliance_fix
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config")
client_id = config.get("config", "API_KEY")
client_secret = config.get("config", "API_SECRET")
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'

linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri='[URL_SERVICE_GOOGLE]/auth/linkedin/callback')
linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)
authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

# make sure to run this command before starting app or configure SSL (how to set inside app, for later)
SSL_ENV = 'export OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT=1'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def init():
    # config
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("config")
    client_id = config.get("config", "API_KEY")
    client_secret = config.get("config", "API_SECRET")
    authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization'
    token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'

    linkedin = OAuth2Session(client_id,redirect_uri='[URL_SERVICE_GOOGLE]/auth/linkedin/callback')
    linkedin = linkedin_compliance_fix(linkedin)
    authorization_url, state = linkedin.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
    # redirect to linked in to get code & session
    return redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/auth/linkedin/callback')
def auth():
    response_url = request.url
    code = request.args.get('code')

    # for some reason response_url is not getting #! values in url at the end; so use code
    linkedin.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret, code=code)

    # Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
    people = linkedin.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json')
    return people.content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==2.1.0
requests_oauthlib==1.3.0
configparser==5.2.0
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.

# https://hub.docker.com/_/python

FROM python:3.10-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.

ENV APP_HOME /app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn

# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.

# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers

# to be equal to the cores available.

# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Impossible to solve, I didn't find the solution myself.